# How would you time out a graphQL query

Tags: server, graphql, apollo

Looking around in documentation relating to graphQL. I have not been able to find out how to time out a query that is taking a long time to return a response.

The server can be started with :

server.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0') => {
console.log(`Server ready`);
});

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout by adding:

```
server.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0') => { console.log(Server ready); })
.then(s => s.setTimeout(<your timeout in millis>));;
```